# User defined aggregation function casuses ORA-22813

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions

When I execute the following script

```
SELECT aggr_func(bki_aggr_input(t.app_date,
                                    t.amount,
                                    t.rate, 
                                    t.term, 
                                    t.OPEN_DATE,
                                    t.STATUS_ID,
                                    t.INF_CONFIRM_DATE,
                                    t.FACT_CLOSE_DATE,
                                    t.PMT_STRING_84M,
                                    t.flag_is_own_contract,
                                    t.OUTSTANDING,
                                    t.CREDIT_LIMIT,
                                    t.TYPE_ID,
                                    t.FINAL_PMT_DATE)) p
  FROM temp_tab t
```

where aggr_func is user defined aggregated funciton
I get the ORA-22813 error

The function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BKI_AGGR_CALC(input_var IN BKI_AGGR_INPUT)
  RETURN BKI_AGGR_OUTPUT
  PARALLEL_ENABLE
  AGGREGATE USING BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES;
```

and the specification  of type `BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES`  is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES AS OBJECT
(
  acc_opn_vs_problem NUMBER,
  pat_opened_12      NUMBER,
  pat_del1p_3        NUMBER,
  max_hist_own NUMBER,
  cntOpenAccounts NUMBER,
  cntAllAccounts NUMBER, 
  ratio_open NUMBER,
  patternsArray NUMBER_TWO_DIMENSIONAL_TAB, 
  unionPattern NUMBER_TAB,
  m_nodelinq NUMBER,
  outstanding_to_credit_limit NUMBER,
  sumOutstanding NUMBER,
  sumCreditLimit NUMBER,
  paymentPatArray NUMBER_TWO_DIMENSIONAL_TAB,
  unionPaymentPat NUMBER_TAB,
  sumMonthPayOpn NUMBER, 
  load_to_avgpaym_24 NUMBER,
  reqMonthPay NUMBER, 
  sumOpenStartInCrisis NUMBER, 
  sumAllCredits NUMBER, 
  ratio_crs_not_sum NUMBER,
  ratio_m_up NUMBER,
  cnt NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(actx IN OUT BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES)
    RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(SELF     IN OUT BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES,
                                       inputVar IN BKI_AGGR_INPUT)
    RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(SELF IN OUT BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES,
                                     ctx2 IN BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(SELF      IN OUT BKI_AGGR_ROUTINES,
                                         returnVar OUT BKI_AGGR_OUTPUT,
                                         flags     IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
)
```

What might cause the error? How I might investigate and fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: According to [this site](http://psoug.org/oraerror/ORA-22813.htm) you exceeded the system limit, try to run your query like this: `SELECT aggr_func(bki_aggr_input(...) from temp_tab t where rownum < 2`, Do you still have this error?

Comment: No, I get an error when the number of rows in temp_tab exceeds 60 rows. Is there a way to increase the limit?

Comment: Check your memory and CPU usage through the Enterprise manager console when you run this query, is there overhead? If so you have to increase these resources, if not, you can try to use parallel operation to use all the resources you have.